# How to fix the new issue "No virtual method zzts()" about Google map (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have this issue in google-maps-api-2 (8.3.0) for Android app. Please help me fix it. Thank a lot.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzts()Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/LifecycleDelegate; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment$zzb; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb' appears in /data/app/com.kerofrog.tribezen-1/base.apk)
```

Comment: wil you pls print complete stackStrace here

Comment: Stop mixing versions of different Play Services libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use play service maps 8.4.0 will fix it

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you